# Removing a date from a date array

Tags: python, pandas

I created an array of `datetime` objects from `2014-12-1` to `2014-12-31`, but i need to remove the `2014-12-29` entry from it. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`Index.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop.html):

```
data = pd.date_range('2014-12-1', '2014-12-31')
print (data)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-12-01', '2014-12-02', '2014-12-03', '2014-12-04',
               '2014-12-05', '2014-12-06', '2014-12-07', '2014-12-08',
               '2014-12-09', '2014-12-10', '2014-12-11', '2014-12-12',
               '2014-12-13', '2014-12-14', '2014-12-15', '2014-12-16',
               '2014-12-17', '2014-12-18', '2014-12-19', '2014-12-20',
               '2014-12-21', '2014-12-22', '2014-12-23', '2014-12-24',
               '2014-12-25', '2014-12-26', '2014-12-27', '2014-12-28',
               '2014-12-29', '2014-12-30', '2014-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

print (data[data != '2014-12-29'])
DatetimeIndex(['2014-12-01', '2014-12-02', '2014-12-03', '2014-12-04',
               '2014-12-05', '2014-12-06', '2014-12-07', '2014-12-08',
               '2014-12-09', '2014-12-10', '2014-12-11', '2014-12-12',
               '2014-12-13', '2014-12-14', '2014-12-15', '2014-12-16',
               '2014-12-17', '2014-12-18', '2014-12-19', '2014-12-20',
               '2014-12-21', '2014-12-22', '2014-12-23', '2014-12-24',
               '2014-12-25', '2014-12-26', '2014-12-27', '2014-12-28',
               '2014-12-30', '2014-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Or:

```
print (data.drop(pd.Timestamp('2014-12-29')))
```

Answer (score 0):

use boolean check for that day

```
df = df[df['date'] !='2014-12-29']
```